# Entity Framework and distributed Systems

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I need some help or maybe only a hint for the right direction.

I've got a system that is separated into two applications. An existing VB.NET desktop client using Entity Framework 5 with code first approach and an ASP.NET Web Api client in C# that will be re-factored. It should be possible to deliver OData. The system and the datamodel is still evolving and so migrations will happen in undefined intervals.

I'm struggling how to manage my database access on the web api system. My favoured approach would be use Entity Framework on both systems but I'm running into trouble while creating new migrations. Two solutions I've thought about:

Shared Data Access dll

The first idea was to separate the data access layer into a separate project and reference from each of the systems. The context would be the same as long as the dll is up to date in each system. This way both soulutions would be able to make a migration. The main problem is that it is much more complicated to update a web api system than it is with the client Click Once Update Solution and not every migration is important for the web api. This would cause more update trouble and out of sync libraries

Database First on Web Api

The second idea was just to use the database first approach an on the web api side. But it seems that all annotations will be lost by each model update.

Other solutions with stored procedures have been discarded because of missing OData support and maintainability.

Has anyone ran into similar conflicts or has any advice oon how such a problem can be solved!